# Difficulty dealing with lots of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been trying to solve this question for a while, tried different approaches, but I can't get to the answer. The question is:

Define $\, \, \,e^{i\beta \Phi}=\rho \left ( \dfrac{\tau_0}{\tau_1} \right )^2$

with $\Phi = \Phi_1 + i\Phi_2$, and being that $\Phi_1, \Phi_2, \rho, \tau_0, \tau_1$ are complex numbers and $\beta$ is a real parameter. Show that:

$\Phi_1 = \dfrac{1}{\beta} \tan^{-1} \left [ i \dfrac{e^{-i\delta}\tau_{0}^{*} \tau_1 - e^{i\delta}\tau_0 \tau_{1}^*}{e^{i\delta}\tau_0 \tau_{1}^*+e^{-i\delta}\tau_{0}^{*} \tau_1} \right ]\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$   and $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \Phi_2=-\dfrac{1}{\beta}\log \left [ \left | \rho \right | \dfrac{\tau_0^* \tau_0}{\tau_1^* \tau_1} \right ]$, with $\rho = \left | \rho \right |e^{i\delta}$

The following part is the best I could do:

First, I worked out the expression

$e^{i\beta(\Phi_1 + i\Phi_2)}=\left | \rho \right |e^{i\delta}\left ( \dfrac{\tau_0}{\tau_1} \right )^2\qquad$ **(1)**

Took the conjugate

$e^{-i\beta(\Phi_1^* - i\Phi_2^*)}=\left | \rho \right |e^{-i\delta}\left ( \dfrac{\tau_0^*}{\tau_1^*} \right )^2\qquad$ **(2)**

Rewrote like this

$e^{i\beta(\Phi_1^* - i\Phi_2^*)}=\dfrac{1}{\left | \rho \right |}e^{i\delta}\left ( \dfrac{\tau_1^*}{\tau_0^*} \right )^2\qquad$ **(3)**

Then I multiplied (1) and (3) and got the following expression

$e^{i\beta (\Phi_1 + \Phi_1^* + i(\Phi_2 - \Phi_2^*))}=e^{2i\delta}\left(\dfrac{\tau_0 \tau_1^*}{\tau_0^* \tau_1}\right)^2$

$e^{2i\beta (Re(\Phi_1) - Im(\Phi_2))}=e^{2i\delta}\left(\dfrac{\tau_0 \tau_1^*}{\tau_0^* \tau_1}\right)^{2}$

$e^{i\beta (Re(\Phi_1) - Im(\Phi_2))}=e^{i\delta}\left(\dfrac{\tau_0 \tau_1^*}{\tau_0^* \tau_1}\right)\qquad$ **(4)**

Also, multiplying (1) and (2), I got:

$e^{i\beta (\Phi_1 - \Phi_1^* + i(\Phi_2 + \Phi_2^*))}= \left | \rho \right |^{2}\left(\dfrac{\tau_0 \tau_0^*}{\tau_1 \tau_1^*}\right)^2$

$e^{i\beta (2i Im(\Phi_1) + 2i Re(\Phi_2))}= \left | \rho \right |^{2}\left(\dfrac{\tau_0 \tau_0^*}{\tau_1 \tau_1^*}\right)^2$

$e^{-\beta (Im(\Phi_1) + Re(\Phi_2))}= \left | \rho \right |\left(\dfrac{\tau_0 \tau_0^*}{\tau_1 \tau_1^*}\right)\qquad$ **(5)**

(5) gives me directly that:

$Im(\Phi_1) + Re(\Phi_2) = -\dfrac{1}{\beta}\log\left[\left | \rho \right |\dfrac{\tau_0 \tau_0^*}{\tau_1 \tau_1^*}\right]\qquad$ **(6)**

After working for a while with (4), I could find this:

$Re(\Phi_1) - Im(\Phi_2) = \dfrac{1}{\beta}\tan^{-1}\left[i\dfrac{e^{-i\delta}(\tau_0 \tau_1^*)^{2} - e^{i\delta}(\tau_0^{*} \tau_1)^{2}}{e^{i\delta}(\tau_0 \tau_1^*)^{2} + e^{-i\delta}(\tau_0^{*} \tau_1)^{2}}\right]\quad$ **(7)**

But from here I don't know how to obtain $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$, I did some other things, but this approach was the one that seemed most correct. I'm also not 100% sure that everything that I did is actually right. Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Is $\tau_2$ a typo for $\tau_0$?

Comment: Maybe start with $\tan\beta\Phi_1=(\sin\beta\Phi_1)/(\cos\beta\Phi_1)$, then $\sin z=(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/(2i)$, $\cos z=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$, and so on.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I fixed, thank you!

Comment: $\Phi = \Phi_1 + i\Phi_2$, yet $\Phi_1,\Phi_2$ are *complex* numbers? There are infinitely many pairs of complex numbers $\Phi_1,\Phi_2$ that would produce the same $\Phi$. Surely you should have $\Phi_1,\Phi_2$ are *real* numbers. In the equations you are trying to prove, $\Phi_2$ is manifestly real. That $\Phi_1$ is real is not so clear, but just requiring $\Phi_2$ to be real is not enough to get a unique solution.

Comment: The fact that $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ were also complex numbers really bothered me, but, after hours of trying,  there is a chance that this question is poorly formulated. I tried solving with $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ being real numbers and got (6) for $\Phi_2$ and (7) for $\Phi_1$. I couldn't get the exactly equation of the statement, but I substituted the solution for $\Phi_2$ in (1) and got (7) for $\Phi_1$ again. Tomorrow I'll be able to contact the professor who brought this question and I think it will end all doubts.

Answer (score -2):

The question statement was wrong, $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are real, so the conjugate of $e^{i\beta \Phi}$ is $e^{-i\beta \Phi_1}e^{-\beta \Phi_2}$. Also, the expression for $\Phi_1$ has the squares just like (7)

Using the same mathematical process, you can obtain $\Phi_1 = (7)$ and $\Phi_2 = (6)$. Thank you all for the help.